# Getting Nested StructType value within an Array inside Dataframe without using explode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write an udf or maybe just some sql query to get the value of a nested Struct.

Schema:

```
StructType(StructField(Parameters,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(**Name**,StringType,true), StructField(Value,StringType,true)),true),true))
```

I want to access the value of **Name**, and filter out data where **Name** is not in ("BOB","Jone", "Adam").

For scale purpose, Explode would be too slow for me. I need better performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference nested columns even within arrays using dot (`.`) in the column name - and then create a simple UDF to check if one of these values match your "interesting names" list. Something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._ 

// "df" contains some data with the right schema:
df.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- Parameters: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
// +--------------------+
// |          Parameters|
// +--------------------+
// | [[Bob,1], [Jane,2]]|
// |[[Adam,1], [Jane,6]]|
// |[[Joan,3], [John,5]]|
// +--------------------+

// we only want the record where names include these:
val interestingNames = Seq("Bob", "Adam")

// UDF checking if there's an intersection between given sequence of names and "interesting" ones:
val areNamesIncluded = udf {
  names: Seq[String] => names.intersect(interestingNames).nonEmpty
}

// use "where" with the result of applying this UDF to Parameters.Name:
val result = df.where(areNamesIncluded($"Parameters.Name"))

result.show()
// +--------------------+
// |          Parameters|
// +--------------------+
// | [[Bob,1], [Jane,2]]|
// |[[Adam,1], [Jane,6]]|
// +--------------------+
```

You can actually do that without the UDF too, using `array_contains` function on each of the "interesting names" and then folding the results using `||`:

```
val result2 = df.where(interestingNames.map(s => array_contains($"Parameters.Name", s)).fold(lit(false))(_ || _))
```

Comment: You have 3 Array, My struct have 1 array, containing a list of Struct. Cannot directly access Name using $"Parameters.Name"